# Minecraft world erased after Xbox system cache cleared?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-legacy-console

My brother recently cleared the system cache on my Xbox. Now, when I launch Minecraft my world shows up but when I go into that world, it's a new/different world.

I reinstalled the update but It still doesn't work and I don't know what to do next. Is there any way to recover my world?

Comment: the game progress as reseted too? like achievements, and also are you signed in the same profile?

Comment: I created this world in creative mode and have spent 50+ hours in this world. Yes I was signed into the same account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not make any difference what so ever as clearing the cache only removes temp files and old files that you have adjusted. Save files should not be touched and they can't even be touched by the cache. These problems are not related to each other.

Stated on the xbox FAQ is :

> The most important part of clearing the cache is knowing what to
>   expect. All downloaded game updates will be removed. So if you have
>   downloaded an auto-update for a game, in order to play it on Xbox Live
>   you will need to re-download it.
>
> **** User game saves, profiles, demos, videos, etc. are not deleted during
>   the process.**

Note the last sentence.

This however does unfortunately mean that if you cant seem to get to your save file in the minecraft world it has been lost. My guess would be that something went wrong while re-downloading the updates and that during that process your save file got corrupted. Minecraft then automatically fixes that but in your case that meant that it created a whole new .world map.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache removes game updates, Minecraft worlds are dependant on updates so what's probably happening is that the updates are being removed (by clearing the cache) which is erasing everything on your world because it's all been made after an update...

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happened to me, what happens is the world is over written with the creation of a new world because, your world contained items that the old version of Minecraft can not support. So even without saving the new world, and after a successful update, your world will no longer be there. However hope is not lost like 99% of the answers you will get. I contacted a forensic data recovery laboratory, the ran a diagnostic on my flash drive (I use a flash drive for storage because my HDD is full, although this works for an HDD as well) and they informed me there was enough traceable data left for a recovery. However it will cost me $200